# Saved xamarin app data in sqlite has cleared

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have used sqlite as my local database in xamarin.forms app. After killing the app, the database gets cleared.

Adding data to the db and reading from db is working and app behaviour is ok but after killing for putting app to the background for a while db records are lost.

```
database = new WorkingTimeHistoryItemDatabase(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "TimeStamps.db3"));
```

I need to have that data until app gets uninstalled

**UPDATE**

this is the WorkingTimeHistroryItemDatabase class

```
public class WorkingTimeHistoryItemDatabase
    {
        readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection database;

        public WorkingTimeHistoryItemDatabase(string dbPath)
        {
            database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
            database.CreateTableAsync<TimeRecord>().Wait();
        }

        public Task<List<TimeRecord>> GetItemsAsync()
        {
            return database.Table<TimeRecord>().ToListAsync();
        }

        //public Task<List<TimeRecord>> GetItemsNotDoneAsync()
        //{
        //    return database.QueryAsync<TimeRecord>("SELECT * FROM [TodoItem] WHERE [Done] = 0");
        //}

        public Task<List<TimeRecord>> GetItemAsync(string id)
        {
            return database.Table<TimeRecord>().Where(i => i.dateOnly == id).ToListAsync();
        }

        public Task<TimeRecord> GetRecentIn()
        {
            return database.Table<TimeRecord>().Where(i => i.inorout == "In").OrderByDescending(i => i.datetime).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }


        public Task<TimeRecord> GetRecentOut()
        {
            return database.Table<TimeRecord>().Where(i => i.inorout == "Out").OrderByDescending(i => i.datetime).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }


        public Task<int> SaveItemAsync(TimeRecord item)
        {
            return database.InsertAsync(item);
        }

        public Task<int> DeleteItemAsync(TimeRecord item)
        {
            return database.DeleteAsync(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the code of `WorkingTimeHistoryItemDatabase(...)` ? Are you "just" creating a sqlite connection and allowing it to create the file if needed... are you copying a pre-existing db from the app bundle, etc...?

Comment: It is the database class that handle all the database calls. It contains the table and database

Comment: @SushiHangover I just add that class. Please take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing is use the "ApplicationData" folder. it will keep your Application specific data and OS knows that there are something that manage by 3rd party.

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing on UWP, check that you don't have the 'Uninstall and then re-install my package.' option checked. This is in UWP Project > Properties > Debug > Start Options.

[image: UninstallCheckBox]

Comment: I'm testing on android amd iOS

Answer (score 0):

I have change the Folder path to "Personal". Seems like it works now.

```
database = new WorkingTimeHistoryItemDatabase(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "TimeStamps.db3"));
```